# Cannot locate memory from QVL ASUS Z97I-PLUS

Tags: pc, memory

I'm looking for whatever highest speed DDR3 2x8GB (2 DIMM slots/Dual Channel & Dual-Sided (DS)) memory is still available somewhere from [this QVL for an ASUS Z97I-PLUS](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1150/Z97I-PLUS/2_Dimm_H97I-PLUS_Z97I-PLUS_New_Memory_test_report.pdf).

Desired Part No.'s in order of preference:

**2800**

- AVEXIR AVD3UH28001208G-4BZ1

**2666**

- AVEXIR AVD3U26661108G-4BZ1
- AVEXIR AVD3U26661208G-4CI

**2400**

- TEAM TLD38G2400HC11CBK
- PANRAM PUD32400C118G2LSK
- AVEXIR AVD3U24001008G-4BZ1

**2133**

- AVEXIR AVD3U21330908G-4BZ1
- G.SKILL F3-2133C10D-16GAB

**2000**

- AVEXIR AVD3U20000908G-4C

*Etc Etc...*

---

I'd prefer getting them from a mainstream retailer if at all possible like:

- Newegg
- Amazon
- Microcenter

But since I can't seem to find any of these anywhere I'm pretty open-ended about that. Definitely needs to still have fully intact manufacturer warranty wherever it's from.

And to just be extra picky, I don't want any 'ugly' memory. No green circuit boards - should be properly heat-shielded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Avexir 2400 @ Altex](https://www.altex.com/AVEXIR-Blitz-11-Series-16GB-2-x-8GB-DDR3-2400MHz-DIMM-Kit-Red-w-White-LED-BLITZ16GB-2400R-P156539.aspx) Altex is only located in Texas but they are super reputable.  I have been using them for over a decade.  You can actually get them on the phone too.  No waiting until Christmas for NewEgg to answer.

[G.SKILL F3-2133C10D-16GAB @ Newegg](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231659&ignorebbr=1&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC-_-pla-_-Memory+%28Desktop+Memory%29-_-N82E16820231659&gclid=Cj0KEQjw7dfKBRCdkKrvmfKtyeoBEiQAch0egYkXhT-64368N4iIXH83V9EtiFzngtMPDzdXiecSaFoaAt9c8P8HAQ&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Comment: Thanks for the finds. The Avexir might be it. I know it's petty but I don't think I can put the bright blue g.skill's in my setup lol.